# HTML5 To Fill An Empty Div

Tags: html, css, video, jquery-animate

I'm trying to have a HTML5 video appear from an empty div and animate to fill the page. The animation is working but the video isn't playing. Any possible suggestions as to why this might be?

CSS

```
.box {
  margin: 30px auto;
  transition: all 2s linear;
  display: block;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.visuallyhidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

</style>
```

HTML

```
<div id="box" class="box">

<video controls autoplay id="back">
<source src="HomepagemockupVid_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

</div>

  <button>TOGGLE VISIBILITY</button>
```

Javascript

```
var box = $('#box');

$('button').on('click', function () {

  if (box.hasClass('hidden')) {

    box.removeClass('hidden');
    setTimeout(function () {
      box.removeClass('visuallyhidden');
    }, 20);

  } else {

    box.addClass('visuallyhidden');

    box.one('transitionend', function(e) {

      box.addClass('hidden');

    });

  }

});
```

Comment: Is the video appearing and not playing, or not appearing *at all*?

Comment: Yeah, the video is appearing and playing upon clicking the button.

Answer (score 0):

I put your code on a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xurav/1/edit) and it seems to work fine after I switched the source tag's `src` attribute to one that actually points to a file

so I changed it from

```
<source src="HomepagemockupVid_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

to

```
<source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

conclusion, are you sure you are pointing to the correct file?